# linux email with Kerio

Tags: linux, kerio

I have Kerio installed in Red Hat enterprise linux, which works well for the P.C. clients however I am not receiving linux generated emails (e.g. cron job output or email generated by `biabam` or `mail`).

Is there a way to have linux use kerio as a email server in the same way as sendmail or postfix works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this link :

http://support.kerio.com/index.php?_m=knowledgebase&_a=viewarticle&kbarticleid=233&nav=0,1,8

Which tells you to create a link to `/opt/kerio/mailserver/sendmail` replacing the `/usr/sbin/sendmail` file with the kerio version, I also had to add 127.0.0.1, port 25 to the SMTP service.

This meant that I can send email using `biabam` and `mail` but the crontab emails (stdout) are not appearing anywhere.

Comment: You may need to set PATH in your crontab so that it knows where to find sendmail.

Comment: It's a sad work-around but unfortunately seems needed on CentOS7 + Kerio 9.2 else anything using the `sendmail` command doesn't work (like local testing, or common in php web apps, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

Im running postfix next to kerio. Configure the kerio SNMTP service so is doesn't listen on 127.0.0.1. Edit postfix main.cf and set inet_interfaces = localhost so postfix only listens to 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like nullmailer can help.

I think I use it on my Kerio box.